# How to make preg_replace to process file name ignoring , file extension?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a file name as  `Dona&ld #Duck .jpg`. I want to replace all the special characters before .jpg or any file extension with `_` (underscore).
Output should be `Don_a_ld__Duck__.jpg`

How to achieve this using preg_replace? I have done as following.

```
$fileName ='Don.a&ld #Duck .jpg';
$fileName = trim($fileName);
$fileExtension = substr($fileName,-4);
$fileName = substr($fileName,0,-4); // file name without extension
echo $filename = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $fileName).$fileExtension;
```

I do not want append file extension separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following solution with a negative lookahead that protects the last dot:

```
$fileName ='Don.a&ld #Duck .jpg';
echo $filename = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9](?![^.]*$)/i', '_', $fileName);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/3CDFCp)

The `(?![^.]*$)` just fails the match if a special char is followed by 0+ chars other than a dot up to the end of the string.

Note that `/[^a-z0-9]/i` matches `_` and replaces with `_`, which is a redundant operation. You may avoid it with a `\W` subpattern:

```
preg_replace('/\W(?![^.]*$)/', '_', $fileName)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead regex:

```
$fileName = preg_replace('/\W(?=.*\.[^.]+$)/', '_', $fileName);
//=> Dona_ld__Duck__.jpg
```

`\W(?=.*\.[^.]+$)` will match a non word character that is followed by DOT and any extension.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkseyq/4)